# How do I import specific parts of the time, e.g. hours or minutes in Python?

Tags: python, datetime

I used to have a program in Python 2 (I am now using version 3) where it would be able to find a specific part of the time, e.g. the hour or the minute. Sadly, I lost the Raspberry Pi this was on. I know that it involves the `from datetime import datetime` command but I don't know how to apply it. There doesn't seem to be anything about this on the web anywhere.

I can't remember exactly how it works but it's probably something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

hour = datetime.hour()
print("The current hour is " + hour + "!")
```

Which would return the following

```
>>>The current hour is 13!
```

Comment: Have you tried that? What's the error you're getting?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html Ya not sure what question you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first check [Python's official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html), as it has a list of all the features for the Standard Library. A simple Google search for "python 3 datetime hour" would've gotten you what you needed.

```
from datetime import datetime

hour = datetime.now().hour
print("The current hour is " + hour + "!")
```

Comment: I looked on that site both earlier and just now, but couldn't find what I was looking for (I didn't really understand a lot of the words, I'm new to coding) but thanks so much for the answer!

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help! I would recommend going through the earlier chapters in the official Python 3 documentation as it's written in the same format but is much easier to read (since it explains the basic data types and operations), and it'll let you learn the right vocabulary. Here's a link to it: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html Additionally, you might also want to check out one of the tutorials linked in the official beginners' guide: https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
```

if you then try print(now) you will have the whole datetime stamp...

> 2016-01-13 20:14:48.836659

You can access them separately with:

```
now.hour
now.minute
now.second
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for:

```
In [29]: hour = datetime.now().hour
In [30]: print('the current hour is {}!'.format(hour))
the current hour is 20!
```

`datetime.now()` is the full current date and time, with separate attributes for day, month, hour, etc:

```
In [31]: datetime.now()
Out[31]: datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 13, 20, 0, 57, 648969)
```